# Uploading Multiple Images In Rails Using Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have 2 models `Products` and `ProductImage`. `Product has_many ProductImages`. I am using paperclip gem.

As you can see below in my binding.pry I have an array of the images locally. How do i upload these images and make a ProductImage. If i continue i get an error `No handler found for "20090a.jpg"`

```
    69: def create_product_images
 => 70:   binding.pry
    71:   params["product_images"].each do |image|
    72:     ProductImage.create(product_image: image, product_id: @form.product.id)
    73:   end
    74: end

[1] pry(#<ProductsController>)> params["product_images"]
=> ["20090a.jpg", "780069_black_l.jpg"]
[2] pry(#<ProductsController>)> @form.product.id
=> 16
[3] pry(#<ProductsController>)>
```

product_image.rb

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  has_attached_file :product_image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "250x250", thumb:"100x100#"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :product_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Here is my Product Create Action. Its not very good. There will be alot of refactoring. As you can see after the `@form.save` i have the `create_product_images` method which is shown above in the first snippet.

```
  def create
    @form = ProductForm.new(
      product_image: product_params[:product_image],
      title: product_params[:title],
      price: product_params[:price],
      size_description: product_params[:size_description],
      shipping_description: product_params[:shipping_description],
      description: product_params[:description],
      tag_list: product_params[:tag_list],
      category_id: product_params[:category_id],
      sizes_by_id: product_params[:sizes_by_id],
      user: current_user
    )
    if @form.save
      create_product_images
      redirect_to @form.product
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new product"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Your product didn't save"
      new
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Product Form

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom" %>
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
            <%= file_field_tag "product_images[]", type: :file, multiple: true, label: "Upload Prouct Image" %>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, include_blank: true, prompt: "Select One Category" %>
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
              <div class='sizes_container' id ='sizes_container_for_<%= category.id %>'>
                <% category.sizes.each do |size| %>
                  <%= label_tag "product_form[sizes_by_id][#{size.id}]", size.title %>
                  <%= text_field_tag "product_form[sizes_by_id][#{size.id}]" %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.input :title, label:"Title"%>
            <%= f.input :price, label:"Price"%>
            <%= f.input :description,label:"Description" %>
            <%= f.input :size_description, label:"Size Details"%>
            <%= f.input :shipping_description, label:"Shipping Details"%>
            <%= f.input :tag_list,label:"Tags - Seperate tags using comma ','. 5 tags allowed per product" %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new product", class: "btn-lg btn-success" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rails Server As Requested

```
Started POST "/products" for ::1 at 2015-12-21 20:24:30 +1000
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S71OiPhlLDY+xBkjeJIUZu5AQZrepnibC8ApZC06jRvRc0qeYDnQZBh4emheR5y64aErezFFu106rhbcnO6DLA==", "product_images"=>["20090a.jpg", "780069_black_l.jpg"], "product"=>{"category_id"=>"3", "title"=>"Test", "price"=>"345", "description"=>"test ", "size_description"=>"test", "shipping_description"=>"test", "tag_list"=>"test"}, "product_form"=>{"sizes_by_id"=>{"7"=>"32", "12"=>"4", "13"=>"", "14"=>"", "15"=>"", "16"=>"", "17"=>"", "18"=>"", "19"=>"", "20"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Create new product"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  SQL (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("title", "price", "description", "category_id", "size_description", "shipping_description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Test"], ["price", 345.0], ["description", "test "], ["category_id", 3], ["size_description", "test"], ["shipping_description", "test"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-21 10:24:31.270461"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-21 10:24:31.270461"]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "product_sizes" ("size_id", "quantity", "product_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["size_id", 7], ["quantity", 32], ["product_id", 16]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "product_sizes" ("size_id", "quantity", "product_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["size_id", 12], ["quantity", 4], ["product_id", 16]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('test'))
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 16], ["taggable_type", "Product"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE ("taggings"."tag_id" = 10 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Product' AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = 16 AND "taggings"."context" = 'tags' AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "context", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "created_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["tag_id", 10], ["context", "tags"], ["taggable_id", 16], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["created_at", "2015-12-21 10:24:31.315652"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
   (13.0ms)  commit transaction

From: /Users/joseph/Documents/Safsy/Website/Safsy/Safsy/app/controllers/products_controller.rb @ line 70 ProductsController#create_product_images:

    69: def create_product_images
 => 70:   binding.pry
    71:   params["product_images"].each do |image|
    72:     ProductImage.create(product_image: image, product_id: @form.product.id)
    73:   end
    74: end

[1] pry(#<ProductsController>)> params["product_images"]
=> ["20090a.jpg", "780069_black_l.jpg"]
[2] pry(#<ProductsController>)> @form.product.id
=> 16
[3] pry(#<ProductsController>)>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 664262ms

Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "20090a.jpg"):
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72:in `block in create_product_images'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:71:in `each'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:71:in `create_product_images'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:51:in `create'
```

Comment: Your params, has not any image file, just a string with filename. Could you share the related form? Also add the right tags for your app, Rails 3 or Rails 4.

Comment: @Зелёный I added the product form. Thank you.

Comment: change `text_field_tag` to the [`file_field_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag) this is tags for the different purpose. Also could you add the Rails server log file, with the related request.

Comment: According to the log file, there is no any images in request to the server.

Comment: @Зелёный i know that. Thats why i am writing a question.